# Can't install .net 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-3.5

When I try to install .net 3.5 I get the follwing message:

> The following feature couldn't be installed:
>
> .NET Framework 3.5
>   (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
>
> Error code: 0x800F081F

I tried with a standalone package and through Windows Features.

Update: Internet connection is fine.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself ? A simple search leads me to [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x800f081f)

Comment: Yes "No component store corruption detected".

Comment: run Dism **DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:d:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess** (replace D: with your mounted Win10 ISO).

Comment: @magicandre1981: that's it!! Thank you!!

Comment: [.NET Framework 3.5 installation error: 0x800F0906, 0x800F081F, 0x800F0907](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2734782) lists possible solutions (the accepted answer being one of them).

Comment: This also might help : `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

Comment: I had the same problem and I tried everything: various DISM commands, uninstalling the .NET 4.5, using Update Assistant, restarting million times, waiting the update for 100 hours — no success. Finally I installed a new version of Windows 10, not the 1809, but the 1709 version. With 1709 everything worked at once.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Please open a command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin and run the following command to install .Net 3.5:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:d:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess
```

(replace D: with your mounted Win10 ISO)

In some environment, DISM fails to fetch the file (Proxy, network policies). The DISM command takes the files from the DVD and you're fine.

If you are MSDN subscriber you can also download the `Windows 10 Features on Demand` ISO, mount the ISO, copy the Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab to C:\Features (or a different folder) and those commands:

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFx3~~~~ /Source:C:\Features
```

If this fails, run this:

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Features\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab
```

Comment: Perfect, worked immediately.

Comment: I was stumped when this was failing as well but then found out I had a group policy blocking me from enabling windows features. `gpedit.msc` >> `Computer Configuration` >> `Administrative Templates` >> `System` >> `Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair`. Set to `Enabled` and check `Contact Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)` - source: http://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-8-and-later/

Comment: What if I have no windows 10 DVD with me. Can we download it from some location and point it to that location?

Comment: @Chandana you can download the ISO from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: i am getting following error: The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.

Comment: @JaiminDave have you installed additional MUI packs before you try to install .net 3.5? if yes, copy the sources\sxs folder from the original DVD/ISO and from an ISO with the MUI language you installed to C:\sxs so that the folder includes all .net 3.5 MUI files from the original language and the new language.

Comment: @StrikeForceZero this worked for me. Thank you for including these steps! They did the trick.

Comment: For me, only the last command `DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Features\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab` worked. It is crucial that the cabinet file resides at a location considered "safe" by Windows. Installing from a USB thumb drive might lead to error 800F0950. I ended up copying the file to C: as shown in the example provided.

Comment: Awesome.. that's also not working.

Comment: Only method that worked for me started with [creating install media](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-10-create-installation-media). Then in admin cmd, `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /all /source:g:\sources\sxs /limitaccess` where g is the location of the Windows 10 dvd iso.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Side by Side (WinSxS) location is probably empty in the registry.

From the GUI called from APPWIZ.CPL this results in error code: 0x800F081F

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing]
"LocalSourcePath"="d:\\sources\\sxs"
```

Check/add the subkey 'Servicing', and the value of 'LocalSourcePath'. It should contain a correct string (e.g. 'd:\sources\sxs'), data type (REG_SZ).
Where "d:" represents your Windows media drive letter.

Comment: All other suggestions here never worked, but this has on 4 PCs for me now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped when this was failing as well but then found out I had a group policy blocking me from enabling windows features. `gpedit.msc >> Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> System >> Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair.` Set to `Enabled` and check `Contact Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)` - source:https://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-8-and-later/

From [strikeforcezero](https://superuser.com/users/279466/strikeforcezero) comment

Answer (score 0):

This may be another option:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/framework-3-offline/

Uploaded on 2016-06-27 - last comments were in 2019.  Appears to work with an air-gapped computer.