# dotNetFramework 3.5 0x8007000d error

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I was installing .netFrameWork 3.5 on Windows 10 from windows feature (Programs and feature > turn on/off windows feature) at the time of downloading my system driver crashed and i had to force restart system. This corrupted dotNetFramework installation.

Now if i try to install .netframework 3.5 from any method it tries to apply changes/Install instead of downloading it and fails to install because of corrupt download.

I have tried all method i found on the internet none of them works and all of them gives same error.

I have tried installing online/offline.
Using Windows ISO Installation files
Group policy and some other methods...(which i don't remember right now)

All of them gives same error. None of them actually tries to install(what i mean they find previous install files and try apply/install those files which are corrupted)

I am looking for temp/download directory where i can delete its files so i can download it again.

Comment: "I have tried all method i found on the internet none of them works."  My crystal ball is in the shop... What exactly did you try already, and what were the results?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/947660/174557

Comment: @Techie007 updated question. Now i hope you have some answers for me in your cyrstall ball. What i really need is to some how delete those downloaded/install files so that any of the tried method can perform clean install. I have no idea where those files are located.

Comment: if DISM fails, copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip the folder and share the zip (Onedrive share link)

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4BD77F0993B8AB8B!2799&authkey=!AG3E5H3sS0Z7i-c&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: the link is down. next time also post @my username so that I get notified that you replied

Comment: @magicandre1981 i reinstalled my windows and everything is ok now.