# Cannot install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, window, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I'm about to give up on installing .NET 3.5. I've tried almost everything now, but nothing seems to work.

- Installing .NET 3.5 from my Windows USB installation via CMD doesn't work, it simply freezes after `Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384` (Command used: `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`). I have also tried copying the `sources` folder to my C drive and run the command, without succes. It should be noted that `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` freezes at the exact same moment.
- Microsoft's installer doesn't work either. If I click the 'Install this feature' button it is stuck at the first phase (Where it's searching for the correct files if I remember correctly)
- It cannot be enabled via the control panel, because it doesn't show up there.
- <del>(This might be a related issue) I cannot search for new updates, for some reason it just keeps searching without finding something or stopping.</del> Nevermind, it found updates after ~2 hours.

I do not get any errors in all the ways that I've tried mentioned above.

Comment: What edition are you running? Is it an upgrade installation? Are you absolutely certain it doesn’t appear in “Turn Windows features on or off”? It should be at the top of the list, “.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)”

Comment: @DanielB I'm running on Windows 10 Home 64 bit. I've upgraded Windows 7 Home 32 bit to Windows 10 Home 32 bit, but later did a clean 64 bit installation of Windows 10. 

.NET Framework 3.5 does indeed appear in "Turn WIndows features on or off", my fault. But, when I check it's checkbox it does the same thing as the Microsoft .NET 3.5 installers do.

Comment: which AV suite do you use?

Answer (score -3):

https://superuser.com/a/947660/639488 
Thanks to magicandre1981

DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:d:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess 
(replace D: with your mounted Win10 ISO)
In some environment, DISM fails to fetch the file (Proxy, network policies). The DISM command takes the files from the DVD and you're fine.