# Similar warning to Can't install .NET 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework, duplicate, .net-3.5

I did not have enough rep to answer or comment on the original question, but I wanted to contribute my findings.
See [Can't install .net 3.5 on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/946988/773029) for the original question.
I received a warning similar to the one below, although the error code might have been different.

> The following feature couldn't be installed:
>
> .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
>
> Error code: 0x800F081F

I tried running the update through the "Windows Features" dialog after each change, and reverted a change when it did not work where applicable.
I tried different VPN's, changing the settings for "Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair" (source: http://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-8-and-later/), however I did not try offline installation using DISM.exe because I did not have a Win 10 image handy.

Answer (score -1):

While in the process of getting the image, I tried the default Microsoft online troubleshooter, and to my surprise installation of .NET 3.5 succeeded after performing the following step:

> Fix Windows file corruption:

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

`sfc /scannow`

(see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors).

Neither tool indicated that there was anything wrong, so perhaps I made a mistake in isolating my tests.

Comment: Hi Kevin, no it's not correct, it should have been an answer to the original [question](https://superuser.com/q/946988/172747), which is protected, so you are not able to answer without some reputation.