# Downgrading from 4.8 version of .NET framework to 3.5.1

Tags: windows-10, installation, .net-framework

I provisioned a new Windows 10 64-bit machine and immediately installed VisualStudio on it. During this installation it prompted me to install some .NET related dependencies.

Running:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> .\MSBuild.exe -version
```

looks like 4.8.37520 is whats installed currently.

I am now trying to install another tool that **requires** .NET 3.5.1 installed.

So my thinking here *was*:

1. Uninstall v4.8.x
2. Download and install v3.5.1

So I go to **Add or remove programs** and type in ".NET" in the search bar and the only item that crops up is:

> "*Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.0.100 (x64) from Visual Studio*"

So now I'm at a total standstill: do I have 4.8.x installed, or 3.0.100? **How does one properly downgrade from 4.8.x to 3.5.1?**

Comment: You cannot downgrade.NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 10 version 1903 and 1909 to .NET Framework 3.5.  .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8+ is a Windows Feature it cannot be installed any other way.  .NET Framework 4.5+ is built into Windows 8+. What version is built-in entirely depends on the build.  The built-in version **cannot** be uninstalled.  **What you specifically have asked to do is not possible.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install .net 3.5 on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946988/cant-install-net-3-5-on-windows-10)

Comment: Hmmm thanks @Ramhound (+1) however according to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10) I can install 3.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: I never said you could not install 3.5 on Windows 8+.  See the duplicate for the correct method.  The article also indicates the method.  **However, you have asked how to replace 3.5 with 4.8 which is NOT possible.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.NET 3.5 is an add-on, it is not included in .NET 4.x.
Just leave 4.8 alone, and also install 3.5.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup yes that article looks like a good place to start. If it is not able to work for some reason, the next thing I would try is to download the installer from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22

Comment: The installer you have linked to is incompatible with Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound Oops, thanks for the correction. Now that you mention it, I guess our domain admin always uses the Windows install media for this, rather than a file.